# Recalling the previous value of a variable?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm a little new to c++ and I hate running across situations where I need to store a previous value in another variable. So my question is, can I make a variable in a sense store two values. I wish I could have the ability to recall previously stored values and use them in other functions.

ex)
Current way

```
int x1 = 5;
int x2 = x1 + 5;
int diff = x2 - x1;
```

What I want to do

```
int x = 5;
x = x + 5;
int diff = x - old_x;
```

Comment: There's no built-in solution, but you can make a class that stores two values, and all the methods/overloaded operators you want to it.

Comment: "what I want to do" it is not clear what *else* you want. An object does not remember previous values. You could write a struct that remembers its history, but it is not quite clear what for

Comment: btw if you need to store an additional value then you need to store an additional value. No matter how you put it, from `x` alone you cannot retrieve a previous value of `x`

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ok. I wasn't sure if there was some kind of bit shifting technique that could be applied. Say I know the variable will not be over certain size, so maybe I could just shift it left or something.

Comment: That's possible, but that would just be an implementation detail, since you still need to write the type yourself (an `int` is an `int` and you can't change that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a minimal class that works for your particular use case:

```
struct Int {
    int val = 0, old_val = 0;
    Int(int i) : val(i) {}
    operator int() { return val; }
    void operator=(int i) { old_val = std::exchange(val, i); }
    int old() { return old_val; }
};
```

and you could use it like this:

```
Int x = 5;
x = x + 7;
int diff = x - x.old();  // diff is 7
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G5hYdv).

Note that this class is minimal, and in practice, you would want to make `Int` model an `int` as closely as possible, with only the additional property of remembering the previous value.

Comment: Trying to make a UDT that pretends it’s a primitive type is always going to end in tears.

Comment: I'm just puzzled about the void operator=.  Shouldn't it better return an Int& to comply with expectations that we have for this operator?

Comment: @Sneftel That's possibly true. I'm not recommending this per se, just answering the question with a possible technique.

Comment: @Christophe Absolutely. There are many improvements that should be made. Like I said, this is just a *minimal* class for the OP's use case.

Comment: @cigien Wow! I'm impress by how quickly you guys could type this up. I hope to have a grasp of c++ like this one day. Thank you all of the replies! Would it be possible instead to store variables as lists and keep track that way?

Comment: Sure, you could have a `std::vector<int> old_vals;` and remember every change  ever made to the variable. I'm not saying I'm recommending this (that depends on your requirements), but it's certainly possible in c++.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that! I don't have any crazy requirements. My programs won't be very large, they're just school project kind of things. My thinking is that the less variables I have to keep track of, the better. So I'll try implanting something like this in my next project just for fun to see what happens, and the limitations of such an idea.

Comment: Good idea, trying out a technique is the best way to figure out the pros and cons. Good luck :)